# Is it possible to define full SELECT clause in USE GO clause?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to define full SELECT clause in USE for a list of databases.

I'm trying to query across all databases in a server to list all available functions. There are about 80 databases so I'm going to use variable table to pass the list of databases to USE clause to be able to switch between every database and run simple query to list functions in there, all through a WHILE loop.

Is it possible to do something like,

```
USE
    (SELECT dBname
     From dBList
     where rowID=@currentRow)
GO
```

IF not, any suggestion to do it less painfully than querying databases one by one?

This is what I have done in MS SQL Server 2014 but no joy,

```
declare @dBaseList Table
( RowID int not null primary key identity(1,1), dBname varchar(100)
)
declare @SeldBname varchar(100)
declare @rowsdBaseList int
declare @currentRow int
insert into @dBaseList (dBname)
SELECT name FROM sys.databases 

set @rowsdBaseList=@@ROWCOUNT
set @currentRow=0

while @currentRow<@rowsdBaseList
begin
    set @currentRow+=1
    use
        (select @SeldBname=dBname
        from @dBaseList
        where RowID=@currentRow)
    Go

    select * from sys.objects where type='FN'
end
```

It should look something like,

```
USE
    dBname1
GO
select * from sys.objects where type='FN'



USE 
    dBname2
GO
select * from sys.objects where type='FN'



USE
    dBname3
GO
select * from sys.objects where type='FN'
.
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use a 3 part name in your query:

```
select * from dBname1.sys.objects where type='FN'
select * from dBname2.sys.objects where type='FN'
select * from dBname3.sys.objects where type='FN'
```

If you'd prefer to do it programmatically, you can use the (unsupported and undocumented) `sp_MSforeachdb` proc:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4 BEGIN select * from ?.sys.objects where type=''FN'' END'
```

The `IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4` conditional excludes system databases, which you presumably don't want.

With regard to using a `SELECT` statement in a `USE` statement, you can't do it as you have specified in your question. However, you can incorporate it into the `sp_MSforeachdb` call, should you need to:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4 BEGIN USE ?; select DB_NAME() AS [DatabaseName], * from sys.objects where type=''FN'' END'
```

Comment: with this way, the script willl return many lists, and it would be better to store all the results in one single table and display them, look at my script, thank you !

Comment: This replicates the functionality of the OP's query. It could easily be expanded should that be their requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Diado, it did the trick but about my question that "is it possible to run SELECT clause in USE GO", any thoughts?

Comment: @afii_palang You can't use a `SELECT` statement as part of a `USE` statement like that, no, but you can incorporate it into the `sp_msforeachdb` call. Have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: thanks for complementary comment @Diado, regarding your point about (unsupported and undocumented) `sp_MSforeachdb` could you give me some direction where this system stored proc could not work properly?

Comment: The issue with the unsupported MS procs (the incredibly useful `sp_who2` is another one btw), is that they can theoretically be changed or even deprecated by Microsoft at any time. Personally I've never seen this cause an issue, but that's anecdotal.

Answer (score 0):

use [sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/)

```
use [yourdatabase_in_which_you_store_the_results]
go
--create table functions_in_alldb(db nvarchar(100),fn_name nvarchar(200))
declare @functions_in_alldb as table(db nvarchar(100),fn_name nvarchar(200))
go
--truncate table functions_in_alldb
go
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 'USE ? 
if ''?'' not in (''master'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''model'',''msdb'')
insert into @functions_in_alldb(db,fn_name) SELECT ''?'',name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = ''FN'' ORDER BY name' 
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command 

select * from @functions_in_alldb
```

Comment: good idea @kemal but trying to find out if possible with variable table than creating a new/temp table

Comment: You can of course use variable table,: I cnaged the script to use varaibale table, if my script is usefull for you, you can upvote it

Comment: thanks @Kemal for further support. It fails with oddest error message, _Must declare the table variable "@functions_in_alldb"_
sorry if I sound a total noob but can't understand why it fails with this error!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Dynamic-SQL? Something like the code below, this is just a sample as I don't have right now my machine to actually test it.

```
SELECT name AS DatabaseName INTO #TEMP FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases

DECLARE @Count INT, @Database VARCHAR(MAX), @Query
    SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP)

WHILE (@Count) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @Database = (SELECT TOP(1) DatabaseName FROM #TEMP)

    SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @Database + '.sys.objects WHERE type = ''FN'''

    EXEC (@sqlCommand)

    DELETE FROM #TEMP WHERE DatabaseName = @Database

    SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP)
END
```

Comment: good idea @randolph #TEMP is a temp table created separately I assume. if so, I'm trying to find out if possible with variable table than creating a new/temp table

Answer (score 0):

Below is a method to return the query results from all databases as a single result set and include the database name.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) =
    STUFF((
    SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT N''' + name + N''' AS DatabaseName, * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + N'.sys.objects where type=''FN'''
    FROM sys.databases
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'), 1, 11,'') + N';';
EXEC(@SQL);
```